# How to validate dynamic values in postman

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-testcase

I want to validate some mandatory fields in my JSON response body. Until now I am using a static way of testing by using hardcoded values something like this

```
json_response = JSON.parse(responseBody);
x=json_response
pm.expect(x).to.equal("abc");
```

But I want to rerun my test scripts so I don't want to change my tests again and again to validate the values. Could anyone please suggest how can I validate my response body.

```
{
    "Name": "John",
    "Contact number": 9826363660,
    "Address": "xyz"
}
```

As every time I will get new values in these keys "Names" "Contact number" "Address"

Comment: what you want to validate , how are these field generated ? please add more details

Comment: In the UI I have a login page where user will enter these 3 values so to test my endpoint I want to validate if Value entered in "Name" key is String, Value entered in "Contact Number" key is Integer, Value entered in "Address" key field is String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  pm.response.json().hasOwnProperty("Name")
```

You can use hasOwnProperty to check whether the field exists

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Do schema validation

```
var schema = {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
        "NAME": {
            "type":"string"
        },
        "ADDRESS": {
            "type":"string"
        },
        "Contact Number": {
             "type":"number"
        }
    }

};

    
  pm.response.to.have.jsonschema(schema)
```

https://postman-quick-reference-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/schema-validation.html

Comment: I have an endpoint which gives the above mentioned response body and I was validating the response with the test like - pm.expect("Name).to.equal("John"); and this very static way of validating by writing the name like ("John") because the value will be changed with every request instead I want something which can validate if the key generated is string. for example - pm.expect("Name").to.equal("String");  so how is it possible to check if the value generated is string or integer as for contact number it will be integer pm.expect("Contact number).to.equal(Integer); please suggest something.

Comment: It's better to do schema validation for that

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I will have a look at that.